# LOAD CSV hangs / does nothing while consuming 10 GB of RAM and 100% CPU

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query to import a huge CSV dataset:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data_ssd/world/test.csv" AS line 
WITH line
WHERE line.lang IS NOT NULL
MATCH (i:Item {id: line.id})
MERGE (s:String {value: line.name, lang: line.lang})
CREATE (i)-[:name]->(s)
```

The CSV contains ~53m items. All `:Item`s are already created (about ~15m; hence the `MATCH`); I'm only missing the `:String`s and relations.

neo4j consumes about 10 GB of memory and the query runs for like 1 hour now, but there's still even not a single `:String` or relationship inserted into the database. neo4j runs at 100% CPU. This is a different behavior than my first query I ran where I inserted all the `:Item`s (I saw the node counter increasing fast over time).

Is there anything wrong with my `LOAD CSV` command?

**Update**: Indexes are created on `:Item(id)`, `:String(value)` and `:String(lang)`.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought: are you sure you have any lines with a `lang` property?

[EDITED] Also, try decreasing the batch size for each periodic commit. The default is 1000 lines. For example: `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500` to specify a batch size of 500.

Also, I see a probable logic error, but it should not be the cause of your main issue ("nothing" happening).

The logic error is this: even if the `MERGE` clause found an existing `(s:String)` node, the `CREATE` clause will always go ahead and create (yet another) `[:name]` relationship between `i` and `s` (even if one or more already existed).

You probably meant something like this, instead:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data_ssd/world/test.csv" AS line 
WITH line
WHERE line.lang IS NOT NULL
MERGE (i:Item {id: line.id})-[:name]->(s:String {value: line.name, lang: line.lang})
```

Comment: Yes, there are lang properties. Just tried the query with a `LIMIT` (like `LIMIT 1000`), and it just worked like a charm. It apparently only has problems with having no LIMIT defined. Yes, `CREATE` is on purpose because there is no such a relation already in the graph. I don't need to check whether it's already there for my understanding. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but with no effect. I even tried a size of 100 or 1 but it didn't worked.